# Unable to send email using form

Tags: php, html

I'am having trouble with the form. It goes through but I never receive an email. I have checked in spam but nothings showed up. Could someone give me hint. Not able to identify error.

```
<div class="contact-form">
<form class="email" action="mailer.php" method="post">
<h3>Kontaktirajte nas!</h3>
<div>
<p>Ime:</p>
input type="text" name="name" />
<p>E-mail:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" />
<p>Naslov   :</p>
<input type="text" name="subject" />
<p>Poruka:</p>
<textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
<input class="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is the php code (mailer.php).

```
$myemail = "example@gmail.com";

$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Enter a subject");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");


if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

$message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

mail($myemail, $subject, $message);


header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Is mail configured at your server ?

Comment: Are you checking it in your localhost or in a server?. If it's in a server make sure that your mail server is configured and if it's your localhost php mail function won't work in your localhost or you need to configure SMTP for this purpose.

Comment: Are you in a free hosting service environment?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and you can reference PHP mail here @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You need to check a FROM address is defined in your code or is set in your php.ini (this could be causing it to get bounced back and not hit your emails)

You don't need a smtp server running if you send out via PHP mail but it's worth testing on a SMTP server to see if this is your issue.

Try W3schools code and see if that sends for you and let us know the results from that...

Link can be found here @ http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sendin emails can be a very thicky thing.

The first thing to check is that you have a valid sender address defined. Some hosts simply refuce sending emails without valid email.

```
$additional_headers = "From: from@example.com\r\n";   
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $additional_headers);
```

Check mail error logs (if you access them), it should give you more insight on what is the problem.